# Replacing a functor by a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently working on refreshing an old C++ project of mine, trying to take advantage of all the good stuff brought by modern C++.
Some part of the project was about accessing an array of uint8_t, returning a uint8_t, a uint16_t or a uint32_t, depending on the data needed.
For the simplicity of the question, I'll leave any endianness related problems aside.

I did the following class, using a functor to access the data :

```
template<std::size_t sz>
class Read
{
public:
    template <std::size_t sz>
    struct Read_traits { };

    template <>
    struct Read_traits<8> { using internal_type = std::uint8_t; };

    template <>
    struct Read_traits<16> { using internal_type = std::uint16_t; };

    template <>
    struct Read_traits<32> { using internal_type = std::uint32_t; };

    template <>
    struct Read_traits<64> { using internal_type = std::uint64_t; };

    using read_type = typename Read_traits<sz>::internal_type;

    template<typename T, ::std::size_t N>
    read_type operator()(const ::std::array<T, N> & arr, const ::std::uint32_t& adr) const {
        read_type returnValue{};
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(read_type) - 1; ++i) {
            returnValue <<= 8;
            returnValue |= arr[adr + i];
        }
        return returnValue;
    };
};
```

Usage is

```
int main()
{
    std::array <uint8_t, 0x4> memory {0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98};
    Read<32> r32;
    auto val32 = r32(memory, 0);
    std::cout << "32 bits: 0x" << std::hex << val32 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> It works the way I want, but I was wondering if it was possible to
>   create a regular function in place of the functor, still using the
>   traits ?
>
> IE replacing the 2 lines functor call :
>
> ```
> Read<32> r;
> auto val = r(memory, 0);
> ```
>
> by a single line function :
>
> ```
> auto val Read<32>(memory, 0);
> ```

I tried a few things that weren't conclusive, and as I'm far from being an expert in templates, I might be chasing after something that's not even doable ...

Thanks for reading me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// Maps 8, 16 and 32 to uint8_t, uint16_t and uint32_t, respectively
template<size_t Size>
using SizedUInt = std::conditional_t<Size == 8, uint8_t,
                   std::conditional_t<Size == 16, uint16_t,
                    std::conditional_t<Size == 32, uint32_t, void>>>;

template<size_t Size, typename T, size_t N>
SizedUInt<Size> read(const std::array<T, N>& arr, uint32_t adr)
{
    SizedUInt<Size> returnValue{};
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(SizedUInt<Size>) - 1; ++i) {
        returnValue <<= 8;
        returnValue |= arr[adr + i];
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

`SizedUInt` is a template alias which selects correct type using nested `conditional_t` template. I've set the "false" type of the deepest `conditional_t` to `void` in order to trigger compilation error, when the template is used with value different than 8, 16 or 32.

---

Or, you could do this, using your template class:

```
// create a temporary of type Read<32> and call its call operator
auto val = Read<32>{}(memory, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, spot on ! I also learned about the last syntax, never thought of that ...

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for `Read` as a class seems to be the definition of `Read_traits`. But you can define the latter outside of the former too. Just a few additional `typename` keywords necessary due to C++ uglyness...

Note that the `sz` template parameter is provided first. When invoking, it is the only parameter used explicitly. The rest is deducted, same as before.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <std::size_t sz>
struct ReadType { };

template <>
struct ReadType <8> { using type = std::uint8_t; };

template <>
struct ReadType <16> { using type = std::uint16_t; };

template <>
struct ReadType <32> { using type = std::uint32_t; };

template <>
struct ReadType <64> { using type = std::uint64_t; };

template <std::size_t sz, typename T, ::std::size_t N>
typename ReadType<sz>::type read(const ::std::array<T, N> & arr, const ::std::uint32_t& adr) {
    using read_type = typename ReadType<sz>::type;
    read_type returnValue{};
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(read_type) - 1; ++i) {
        returnValue <<= 8;
        returnValue |= arr[adr + i];
    }
    return returnValue;
};

int main()
{
    std::array <uint8_t, 0x4> memory {0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98};
    auto val32 = read<32>(memory, 0);
    std::cout << "32 bits: 0x" << std::hex << val32 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your post as your answer is exactly what I asked for ... but I'll keep joe_chip's answer as it's better than what I asked in the first place ;)